# How can I select only th row that has a specific sum total less than in Django?

Tags: django, postgresql

I have this Model

```
class statics(models.Model):
   user= models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 100, decimal_places = 8, default=0)
```

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
id | amount
1  | 21
2  | 20
3  | 10
4  | 15
```

I want in results only to select the rows that the sum of thier amount is less then 55
In this case the result should be

```
id | amount
1  | 21
2  | 20
3  | 10
```

because all these rows amount sum is less than 55

This is what I tried to do:

```
 data=statics.objects.annotate(total=Sum('amount')).filter(total__lte=55)
```

But it didn't work as all rows had the total always equal to their amount not the sum

Comment: Your question is not sufficient to give an accurate answer. I guess you can see there are numerous possibility to return such rows. Did you mean you want to start from first id and stop at the largest Id such that sum total is less than 55 and return those IDs?

Comment: yes i start from first id till last one

Answer (score 0):

`annotate` is a per object aggregation, so you are just summing up the object `ammount` field with nothing else, that is why it returns the same value. If you want the total value of the `ammount` fields inside the QuerySet, you need to `aggregate`:

```
Statics.objects.aggregate(Sum('amount'))
```

Although, that is just a partial solution for what you want. Because, `.aggregate` does not return objects of the QuerySet, but instead a dictionary with the value of the aggregation:

```
{'amount__sum': Decimal('66')}
```

So the only way that I could think of is to dynamically increase the QuertSet objects until the sum reaches the limit. Note the this solution worsens in performance the more values closer to zero you have.

views.py

```
def show_statics(request):
    ammount_limit = 55
    context = {}

    queryset = Statics.objects.all()[:1]
    sum = queryset.aggregate(sum=Sum('amount'))['sum']

    if not queryset:
        messages.error(request, "No data")
        return render(request, 'show_statics.html')

    if sum >= ammount_limit:
        context = {'queryset': queryset, 'sum': sum}

    else:
        num_objects = 2
        while sum <= ammount_limit:
            aux = Statics.objects.all()[:num_objects]
            aux_sum = aux.aggregate(sum=Sum('amount'))['sum']

            if len(aux) == len(queryset):
                messages.warning(request, "not enough objects to reach ammount_limit")
                break

            if aux_sum > ammount_limit:
                break
            elif aux_sum == ammount_limit:
                queryset = aux
                sum = aux_sum
                break
            else:
                queryset = aux
                sum = aux_sum
                num_objects += 1

    context = {'queryset': queryset, 'sum': sum}
    return render(request, 'show_statics.html', context)
```

show_statics.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {% if messages %}
        <ul class="messages">
            {% for message in messages %}
            <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}

    {% if queryset %}
        <p>Sum: {{sum}}</p>
        <hr>
        {% for obj in queryset %}
            <p>{{obj.id}} | {{obj.amount}}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```